# The specified object was not found in the store

Tags: import, office365, exchange-server-2007, pst

I have an Office 365 domain for a client and I'm currently trying to import PST file to the O365 addresses.
I googled the question, and found the [Microsoft Exchange PST Capture](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36789).

I installed it, provided the administrator credentials of my Office 365 domain and started the import. But it failed with this error:

> Import error: The specified object was not found in the store

In the logs (`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Exchange\PST Capture\Logs\PST Capture Service`), I can find this:

```
10:28:22.226|Debug  |ImportListImporter  |11 |Error importing D:\ExportPst\dirfond.pst from C:\PSTStaging\13ec9aa3-8887-41fd-8a97-d2f74d7408de.pst
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.ImportEngine.PstEwsImporter.BindToCorrectFolder(ExchangeService service, ImportOptions options, WellKnownFolderName& rootname, Boolean& failover)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.ImportEngine.PstEwsImporter.StartImport(String pstPath, String passWord, ImportOptions options, List`1& problems)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.CentralService.ImportListImporter.<>c__DisplayClass8.<ImportFile>b__5(Object param0)

10:28:22.227|Debug  |ImportListImporter  |11 |Keeping Exception ex for result 12459148
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.BindToFolder[TFolder](FolderId folderId, PropertySet propertySet)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.ImportEngine.PstEwsImporter.BindToCorrectFolder(ExchangeService service, ImportOptions options, WellKnownFolderName& rootname, Boolean& failover)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.ImportEngine.PstEwsImporter.StartImport(String pstPath, String passWord, ImportOptions options, List`1& problems)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.CentralService.ImportListImporter.<>c__DisplayClass8.<ImportFile>b__5(Object param0)

10:28:22.232|Debug  |ImportListImporter  |13 |Rethrow od result 12459148

10:28:22.234|Trace  |DBImportFile        |13 |Saving 58 False Error D:\ExportPst\dirfond.pst

10:28:22.318|Error  |ImportListImporter  |13 |Import error: 
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store.
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.CentralService.ImportListImporter.ImportFile(RepositoryImportFile file)

10:28:22.320|Error  |Import Action       |13 |Error during import
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store.
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.CentralService.ImportListImporter.ImportFile(RepositoryImportFile file)
   at RedGate.PSTImporterForExchange.CentralService.Actions.StartImportAction.RunImport(Object state)
```

The destination mailboxes exists.
Is that because the email address from Exchange 2007 (where the PST file is from) is different than the O365 one ?

I can't find anything about this, so your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In the same boat with EWS.... what a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by setting permissions for the user that is running the command to the mailbox.

> Add-MailboxPermission -Identity  [TargetMailbox]  -User
>   [ExecutingAccount] -AccessRights FullAccess